# Sql Server pivot columns into rows fill NULL with zero or existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have table in SQL Server for now considered temp table as below :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Period') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Period
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Account') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #account
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BudgetDetail') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BudgetDetail

create table #Period([PeriodId] int,[PeriodName] varchar(50),CompanyID int)
insert into #Period values(1,'P1',100171)
insert into #Period values(2,'P2',100171)
insert into #Period values(3,'P3',100171)
select * from #Period

create table #account([AccountId] int,CompanyID int)
insert into #account values(1,100171)
insert into #account values(2,100171)
insert into #account values(3,100171)
select * from #account


create table #BudgetDetail([PeriodId] int,[AccountId] int,[Amount] money,CompanyID int)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(1,1,101,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(1,2,100,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(1,3,160,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(2,1,110,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(2,2,170,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(2,3,0,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(3,1,120,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(3,2,180,100171)
insert into #BudgetDetail values(3,3,0,100171)

select * from #BudgetDetail

Below is my query :
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @CompanyID int = 100171

 SELECT 
  @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([PeriodName] + ';' + 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,[PeriodId]))
  FROM 
  #Period       
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')  

 SET @query = 'SELECT *  FROM   
     (SELECT bd.AccountId, PeriodName, Amount    
      FROM          
     #Account acc LEFT JOIN
     #Period pr ON acc.CompanyID = pr.CompanyID LEFT JOIN
     #BudgetDetail bd ON acc.AccountId = bd.AccountID AND acc.CompanyID = 
      bd.CompanyID AND 
     pr.PeriodId = bd.PeriodId AND 
     pr.CompanyID = bd.CompanyID
    ) x  
    PIVOT
    (  
       SUM(Amount)
     FOR PeriodName IN (' + @cols + ')  
    ) p '
  print @query
  EXECUTE(@query);
```

I get below output when I run above query :
This is my output

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;AccountId</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 25.5771%;">&nbsp;P1;1</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 34.4229%;">&nbsp;P2;2</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;P3;3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;1</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 25.5771%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 34.4229%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;2</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 25.5771%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 34.4229%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;3</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 25.5771%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 34.4229%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td style="height: 21px; width: 19%;">&nbsp;NULL</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The above output is correct but instead of NULL values I want Amount column values Like below :

I want output like Fill NULL value with Amount like below :

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;AccountId</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;P1;1</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;P2;2</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;P3;3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;1</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;101</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;110</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;120</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;2</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;100</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;170</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;180</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;3</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;160</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;0</td>
<td style="height: 21px;">&nbsp;0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [PeriodName] couln is not avialble in #Period Table

Comment: @Srini131 Thanks for the reply. Let me correct that.

Comment: CompanyID also missing it seems

Comment: Now you can check

Comment: checking your updated script now, for future reference, these type of questions would be made easier with a dbfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the way you are combining PeriodId and PeriodName for the values to check for in the pivot.

your @cols comes out as [P1;1],[P2;2],[P3;3]
but your pivot is only using PeriodName to check for these values

```
PeriodName IN (' + @cols + ')
```

Assuming that you are combining period name and id for a specific purpose, what you should have done is to create the same value in the select

```
acc.AccountId, Amount, PeriodName + ';' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),pr.PeriodId) as PeriodKey
```

and then use this combined column in the pivot.

```
FOR PeriodKey IN (' + @cols + ')
```

The result dynamic sql is

```
SET @query = '
   SELECT
       * 
   FROM   
       (SELECT
           acc.AccountId, Amount, PeriodName + '';'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),pr.PeriodId) as PeriodKey
        FROM          
           #Account acc
           LEFT JOIN #Period pr ON
               acc.CompanyID = pr.CompanyID
           LEFT JOIN #BudgetDetail bd ON
               acc.AccountId = bd.AccountID
           AND acc.CompanyID = bd.CompanyID
           AND pr.PeriodId = bd.PeriodId
           AND pr.CompanyID = bd.CompanyID
       ) x  
       PIVOT
       (  
           SUM(Amount)
           FOR PeriodKey IN (' + @cols + ')  
       ) p '
```

[dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3693fb7956f6614f7e9e1a61af4b8e8d)

Comment: Thank you so much. You did a fantastic job. You saved my lots of time. Thanks Again.

Comment: Hi, I need your help, when I put filter criteria lats say I have column Id(int) and I have condition like this AND (Id = '+convert(varchar,@Id)+' or  '+convert(varchar,@Id)+' = 0).
It returns only 1 row with NULL values Instead of it I want the no. of rows equals to AccountId.

Comment: Hi, Firstly, you should avoid concatenating parameters into the dynamic sql. see this SO post on how to execute dynamic sql with parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036745/t-sql-how-to-use-parameters-in-dynamic-sql
Secondly, you intentions or what you are trying to achieve with the condition is not clear. I would suggest post a separate question, explaining what results you are trying to achieve, what statements have you tried, and possibly a dbfiddle link so that we can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Hi @henrylu, I have filter criteria in query is "Id" param in #BudgetDetail. When I run query with "Id" param It will not generate the expected result. You can check it well using dbfiddle : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7eb2c448e3fbbf762f9243920606301d

Comment: The reason the pivot is not returning the account ID's is because your select query uses bd.AccountId and not acc.AccountId. Since your BudgetId filter is 44 and only data is available for 33, bd will return no rows and thus bd.AccountId is always null. I've updated the answer to reflect the change you will need so that account id comes from acc and not bd.

Comment: Thanks @HenryLu, I got your point and it works fine but when I pass 'Id' param value other than 33 I get the expected output but except zero(0) value. You can see at http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3d5b22a500c214d1ce83e2f3a9a91d30
I want NULL or Zero value for Amount

Comment: Hi @Henry, My problem is resolved. Thank you for your time. Really Appreciated

Comment: Not a problem. If my answer resolved your issue, please mark it as the answer on the post so that others know. if it was some other solution that you found, please post as a separate answer for others benefit

Comment: Just removed OR condition from Id param.