# getting error while converting to date time in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting error like:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spQueryMgt, Line 106 [Batch
>   Start Line 13]     Conversion failed when converting date and/or time
>   from character string.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQueryMgt]
    @Mode               varchar(50)='',
    @Query_Form         varchar(20)='',
    @Patient_ID         bigint=0,
    @Verified_By        bigint = 0,
    @Verified_Date      datetime=''
AS
BEGIN
IF(@mode='Post_Query')
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'Update '+ CONVERT(varchar(12), @Query_Form) +' Set
        Verified_By='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Verified_By)+',
        Verified_Date='''+CONVERT(datetime, @Verified_Date,20)+'''
        where Patient_ID = '+CONVERT(varchar(12), @Patient_ID)

        EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;

END
END
```

Comment: Can you add `PRINT @sql` inside procedure above `EXEC sp_exe...` ?

Comment: Try to remove `convert` from `@Verified_Date`. Also be cautious of injection

Comment: `Verified_Date='+CONVERT(datetime, @Verified_Date,20)+'` this change may work.

Comment: as a sidenote, its better to initialize datetime parameter with null in stead of ''

Comment: You might want to check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036745/) how to do dynamic sql in a safer way. Because [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to -

```
SET @sql = N'Update '+ CONVERT(varchar(12), @Query_Form) +' Set
        Verified_By='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Verified_By)+',
        Verified_Date='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @Verified_Date,20)+'''
        where Patient_ID = '+CONVERT(varchar(12), @Patient_ID)
```

There is issue with your `convert` function. You are converting `@Verified_Date` to `datetime` and concatenating `datetime` to `varchar` string.

Comment: But the value is of date time.

Comment: Yes, You are correct i.e., value is of datetime but we can't concatenate datetime value with varchar string.

Comment: @DhruviParikh This is not a correct way to use `sp_executeSQL` procedure. Please research about it and also as mentioned by @uzi , your procedure allowing SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you where converting datetime back into datetime, and then tried to concatinate which gives you that exception.

But also, by initializing parameters to '' and 0 you are filling your database with unnesesary values like '' for varchars and  `1900-01-01` for datetime columns and even worse 0 in integer columns.
Is that what you really want ? I doubt it.
It will be impossible to determine if a field was intentionaly set to this value or was left empty and get you into troubles later.

You can do your procedure like this to get NULL values in empty parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQueryMgt] (
  @Mode               varchar(50) = NULL,
  @Query_Form         varchar(20) = NULL,
  @Patient_ID         bigint = NULL,
  @Verified_By        bigint = NULL,
  @Verified_Date      datetime = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  IF @mode ='Post_Query'
  BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

     if (@Query_Form is not null) and (@Patient_ID is not null) -- nu use in updating when no table or id is given
     begin
         SET @sql = N' Update ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), @Query_Form) +
                     ' Set Verified_By = ' + isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Verified_By), 'null') + ',' +
                     ' Verified_Date = ' + case when @Verified_Date is null then 'null' else '''' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @Verified_Date, 20) + '''' end + 
                     ' where Patient_ID = ' + isnull(CONVERT(varchar(12), @Patient_ID), 'null')

         EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
     end
  END
END
```

EDIT
As mentioned in the comments you should also take care of sql injection, and that makes your procedure safer, but also even easier

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQueryMgt] (
  @Mode               varchar(50) = NULL,
  @Query_Form         varchar(20) = NULL,
  @Patient_ID         bigint = NULL,
  @Verified_By        bigint = NULL,
  @Verified_Date      datetime = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON 

  IF @mode = 'Post_Query'
  BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

     if (@Query_Form is not null) and (@Patient_ID is not null) -- nu use in updating when no table or id is given
     begin
         SET @sql = N'Update @P0 ' + 
                     'set Verified_By = @P1, ' + 
                     '    Verified_Date = @P2 ' + 
                     'where Patient_ID = @P3'

         EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
              N'@P0 varchar(20), @P1 bigint, @P2 bigint, @P3 datetime', 
              N'@P0 = @Query_Form, @P1 = @Verified_By, @P2 = @Verified_Date, @P3 = @Patient_ID'
     end
  END
END
```